# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable while no iteration exists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

I am trying to do a BFS while Python gives me an int object not iterable error.

Part of the code is

```
visited, queue = set(), collections.deque( ((0, 0), [ (0, 0) ] ) ) 
# tuple: current location,  path
while queue: 
    vertex = queue.popleft()
    i,j=vertex[0]
    if i+1<=dim-1 and (i+1, j) not in visited and X[i+1, j]==0:
        visited.add(( i+1, j) )
        temp=( (i+1, j), vertex[1]+[(i+1, j)])
        if temp[0]==(dim-1, dim-1):
            return True, temp[1]
        queue.append(temp)
```

[image]

Under the while loop, I am doing any other iteration at all!

Comment: `not in visited` if visited is an int, you will get that error: the `in` operator will try to iterate the sequence to check for the value.

Comment: `i, j = <expression>` implies that `<expression>` is iterable and has exactly two elements. Whereas in your case, the expression (`vertex[0]`) yields an integer, which is not iterable.

Comment: So see, you actually have (at least) two iterations in the block you posted, even if they're not obvious.

Comment: @Dunes  i am pretty sure that's the answer, you should post it.

Comment: @ Jared Smith My `visited` here is a set containing tuples of the form (int, int)

Comment: Now I find it's more of a Python data structure problem: input`collections.deque( ((0, 0), [ (0, 0) ] ) ) ` actually becomes`deque([[(0, 0)]])`

Answer (score 1):

`i, j = <expression>` implies that  is iterable and has exactly two elements. Whereas in your case, the expression (vertex[0]) yields an integer, which is not iterable.

The statement: `i, j = vertex[0]` is roughly equivalent to:

```
iterator = iter(vertex[0])
i = next(iterator) # this is iteration, but outside of a loop
j = next(iterator)
try:
    next(iterator)
except StopIteration:
    pass
else:
    raise ValueError
```

Your code should either be

```
i = vertex[0]
j = vertex[1]
```

or

```
i, j = vertex
```

Comment: I don't know how but it shouldn't be like this. The things inside my `queue` are tuples of the form (tuple, list), therefore `vertex[0]`  should give me the first inner tuple

Comment: Try printing out `vertex`  before this statement to see what it is. Something is wrong with how you manage your queue.

Comment: It looks like your initial construction of the queue is wrong. It creates a two element queue as a opposed to a one element queue with a tuple of a tuple and a list.

Comment: I tested on terminal. Indeed, first `popleft()` gives me only `(0, 0)`