# Python Dataclass gives me 'function' object has no attribute '__mro__'?

Tags: python, anaconda, python-dataclasses

As in the last question:[TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable while no iteration exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54556930/typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable-while-no-iteration-exists), I find a problem in my program. That is:
In Python,

- `set( (0,0) )`actually gives you `{0}`, but I want `{(0,0)}`
- `collections.deque( ((0, 0), [ (0, 0) ] ) ).popleft()`actually gives you `(0,0)` , whereas I want `((0, 0), [ (0, 0) ] )`

So now I',m thinking about designing data classes of my own. Yet in test code I came across an 'function' object has no attribute "**mro**" problem.

**Test code 1**:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
def DequeItems():
    current:tuple
    path:list

a=DequeItems(current=(0, 0),\
        path=[ (0, 0) ] )
print(a)
```

**Test code 1 error screenshot**:

[image]

**Test code 2**:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(init=True)
def Pair():
    visit:tuple

a=Pair( visit=(0,0)) 
print(a)
```

**Test code 2 error scrrenshot**:
[image]

My Python version is Anaconda 3.6.8

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), this module "provides a decorator and functions for automatically adding generated special methods <..> to user-defined __classes__". Is something that starts with `def` a class?

Comment: From my understanding, this decorator will take care of many methods like `__init__`, `__eq__` for you @ForceBru

Comment: Yes, you're right. Do _functions_ normally have these methods? Would it make sense for _functions_ to have them?

Comment: Write `set(((0,0),))` to get set of tuples

Comment: @ForceBru Of course normally you don't need these complicated things. But in my case I need a class to store things.

Comment: @JiapengZhang, yes, you need a _class_, but `DequeItems` and `Pair` are __functions__!

Comment: @ForceBru Oh. I didn't realize that! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `set` has to be an iterable whose elements are the desired set items. `set( (0,0) )` has an iterable as an argument, but its elements are 0 and 0, not a tuple `(0,0)`. You need `set([(0,0)])`. The same goes for `deque`; you need an iterable *containing* the tuple `((0, 0), [ (0, 0) ] )`, so

```
collections.deque([((0, 0), [ (0, 0) ] )])
```

As for the error you are seeing, `function` doesn't have an `__mro__`, because it doesn't need one. It's base class is always `object`, and you cannot inherit from `function` to create a class whose MRO would need to access `function`'s hypothetical MRO.

As to *why* your data class raises that error, it's because the `dataclass` decorator has to decorate a *class*, not a function.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class DequeItems:
    current:tuple
    path:list

a = DequeItems(
        current=(0, 0),
        path=[(0, 0)]
    )
print(a)
```